# Add a record to an Algolia Index only if it does not exists

Tags: algolia

I was wondering how can i POST in a single request (without fetching results for the given attribute) a pretty simple record to an Algolia Index without creating repeated instances.

e.g:

```
category: {
  name: String // This should be unique
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't such "addObject if not exists" feature based on the record content but if you use the category name as the objectID of your record; the second time you'll add the object, it will just replace the previous instance.

```
{
  objectID: "mycategoryname",
  moreattributes: "if needed",
  [...]
}
```

Would that work?